# Permutations of 9 total letters, using at least 7 letters.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Original Question:

> How many different strings can be made from the letters in "EVERGREEN"
>   using at least 7 of it's letters.
>   Note that the 4 "E"s and 2 "R"s are indistinguishable.

I understand how to use permutations with repetition to determine the number of ways for 9 total letters, but the "at least 7 letters" part stumps me.

Without that condition, it would be 9!/4!2! possible permutations.

Now, should I simply subtract some other number of ways? Perhaps the number of permutations that are less than 7?

How should I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: How did you obtain $9!/8$?

Comment: I may be wrong, but in the lecture slides he explains that if all letters WERE unique, it is 9! ways to arrange 9 letters. But in an example he said you divide by how many permutations would look the same (i.e. COOL and COOL are the same even if the two Os are in a "different" order).

Comment: Since there are $4$ Es and $2$ Rs in EVERGREEN, we must choose four of the nine positions for the Es, two of the remaining five positions for the Rs.  The remaining three distinct letters can be placed in the remaining three positions in $3!$ ways, which yields $$\binom{9}{4}\binom{5}{2}3! = \frac{9!}{4!5!} \cdot \frac{5!}{2!3!} \cdot 3! = \frac{9!}{4!2!}$$ distinguishable arrangements of the letters of the word EVERGREEN when all nine letters are used.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I will edit the post.

Comment: @BenKatz Please, if you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using 9 letters the number of different words is $\binom{9!}{4!2!}$

to find how many words you can form with 8 letters you have to perform the same calculation on each of the following set of letters

EEEVRRGN, EEEERRGN, EEEEVRGN, EEEEVRRN, EEEEVRRG

e.g. for the first one the number of words is $\binom{8!}{3!2!}$, and so on

then you have to add to the previous results the same calculation for 7 letters considering all the different sets, and precisely

EEVRRGN, EEERRGN, EEEVRGN, EEEVRRN, EEEVRRG, EEEERGN,EEEERRN,EEEERRG, EEEEVGN, EEEEVRN,EEEEVRG, EEEEVRR

I don't know whether there exists a different direct way

Comment: So in each of those 5 sets of letters, are you just taking a different letter away? Like 5 different cases?

Comment: yes, in this way you obtain all the different words of 8 letters

Comment: Wouldn't there be more than 5 different ways though? Or is it less because the letters are indistinguishable?

Comment: for each one you have to perform the ame calculation you did for nine letters

Comment: I've added something to explain the concept better

Comment: I'm not sure how you arrived at "EEEVRRGN, EEEERRGN, EEEEVRGN, EEEEVRRN, EEEEVRRG"

Comment: you have to eliminate one letter from the nine initial letters in order to obtain different set each of 8 letters; for each one of these set you can perform the ordinary calculation of permutation as for the initial set of 9 letters; then you have to do the same calculation for 7 letters and sum all the results

Comment: I've added also all the different sets of 7 letters

Answer (score 0):

If you use exponential generating functions you can reduce the problem to computing the coefficient of $x^7/7!$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^3(1+x+x^2/2!)(1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+x^4/4!)$.

This is messy but not overwhelming to do by hand if one uses appropriate tricks (eg replace $(1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+x^4/4!)$ with $(x^3/3!+x^4/4!)$ and $(1+x)^3$ with $(3x+3x^2+x^3)$ since the other terms don't contribute to the $x^7$ term)

The most reasonable alternative is to divide up the counting into cases based on the possible partitions that may result from such a set:

- Taking 4 E's and 1 each of three out of V,R,G, and N.
- Taking 4 E's, 2 R's, and 1 each of two out of V, G, and N.
- Taking 3 E's, and 1 of each of V,R,G, and N.
- Taking 3 E's, 2 R's, and 1 of each of V,G, and N.
- Taking 2 E's, 2 R's, and 1 of each of V,G, and N.

Comment: This went way over my head but thank you anyway!